# Using Regex in mongodb

Tags: regex, mongodb

I'm trying to use regular expressions in my mongodb queries. 
According the documentation I can run a regular expression in my query like this :

```
db.customers.find( { name : /^foo.bar/ } );
```

But **is there a way to store a regex in the document and retreive the documents where the regex  matches a supplied string ?**

Example document :

```
{ _id : SomeID , matcher : "/^foo.bar/" }
```

Query (in my dreams).

```
db.customers.find( { matcher : { $matches : "foozbar" } );
```

Comment: Howmany number of rows are there in your collection? I think this is not working with large number of row in collection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use [arbitrary JavaScript in queries](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-JavascriptExpressionsand%7B%7B%24where%7D%7D).

```
> db.customers.insert({_id: 9, matcher: '^foo.bar'})
> db.customers.insert({_id: 318, matcher: '^bar.qux'})
> db.customers.insert({_id: 44, matcher: '^foo[a-z]+r'})
> db.customers.find(function() {
...     return RegExp(this.matcher).test('foozbar');
... })
{ "_id" : 9, "matcher" : "^foo.bar" }
{ "_id" : 44, "matcher" : "^foo[a-z]+r" }
```

Comment: @Vasiliy-foronov This is working good for small number of rows in collection. But if I have 200k rows in collection, it is not working. I think there is a problem of timeout. Let me your suggestion.

Comment: @MaulikVora My answer runs JavaScript on MongoDB, which is slow. I don’t know if there is any other way to do this. Perhaps you could go the other way around: do you really need to match against plain, unrestricted regexes?

Comment: its like using $where query, it cannot use any indexing so it would be slow. I think it's as good as it gets.